# Repeating a Function within a Function in R

Tags: r

I have a function that runs a simulation a number a times.  It creates a matrix of 0s and 1s and then checks for a 'TIC TAC TOE' win.  I want to be able to repeat that function 'n' number of times.  Here is my code...

```
    function (SimSize,nrow,ncol)
{
count.win = 0
#Beginning Grand Loop
for(i in 1:SimSize){

#creating TicTacToe board of 1s and 0s
game = matrix(sample(c(0,1),replace=T,size = nrow*ncol),nrow=nrow)

#Check for any wins

if( any( 
any(colSums(game)==ncol),
any(rowSums(game)==nrow),
any(sum(diag(game))==ncol),
any(sum(diag(apply(game,2,rev)))==ncol))
)
count.win = count.win+1
}
#calculate the probability of a win per simulation size
p.win = count.win/SimSize
out = list(SimSize,count.win,p.win)
out
}
```

I want to be able to plot a SimSize vs count.win graph at the end.  But to do that I need the selected SimSize to be run 'n' times.  Any help??

Comment: Take a look at `replicate(n, function)` to repeat a function `n` times

Answer (score 1):

If I assume you assign your function as `tictac<-function(SimSize,nrow,ncol) {}`

then you could simply do

`results<-lapply(1:100,function(x) tictac(x,3,3))`

You will want to change your function so that its only output is `count.win`

Answer (score 0):

```
tictactoe_simulation <- function (sim_size, n_row, n_col) {
  count.win = 0

  #Beginning Grand Loop
  for(i in 1:sim_size){
    #creating TicTacToe board of 1s and 0s
    game = matrix(sample(c(0,1),replace=T,size = nrow*ncol),nrow=nrow)

    #Check for any wins
    if( any( 
      any(colSums(game)==ncol),
      any(rowSums(game)==nrow),
      any(sum(diag(game))==ncol),
      any(sum(diag(apply(game,2,rev)))==ncol))
    )
      count.win = count.win+1
  }
  #calculate the probability of a win per simulation size
  p.win = count.win/SimSize
  out = list(SimSize,count.win,p.win)
  out
}
replicate(10, tictactoe_simulation(10,3,3))
```

Another solution could be closures, where you define in an outer funtion the amount of runs and in the inner the set up for the simulation. [see](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures)

Additionally, I would suggest naming your variables in camelCase or with underscore. Especially in the case of `nrow` and `ncol` which are base functions.